# Checking if a html tag exist on this scenario using JS

Tags: javascript, html

The HTML part looks like this:

```
<select class="ue-select-box box-model" name="metric-name">                             
  <option value="1" selected>Logins (including from CRM)</option>
  <option value="2">Listened to a Call (including from CRM)</option>
  <option value="15">Set up a New Report/Edited a Report</option>
  <cfif session.accountId NEQ 5>
     <option value="13">Staff Activity - Deactivate</option>
  </cfif>                                  
</select>
```

1. First question is what can I use to check if this option exist? I know there is a method (myfile.getElementsByTagName("")) but in my case I have a lot of tags that has the tag-name "option".
2. If there is a method to check if the option exist, is it gonna work on this scenario since my option is on the page even though is displayed only when accountId from session is not equal to 5

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: I don´t know what cfif does but you can do document.getElementsByClassName('ue-select-box')[0] and check if one of the option children has a value of 13

Comment: @juvian. cfif it is just an IF statement in coldfusion. So how would you do that in JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. First question is what can I use to check if this option exist? I know there is a method (myfile.getElementsByTagName("")) but in my case I have a lot of tags that has the tag-name "option".

You can use `document.querySelector` to find the first matching element for any valid CSS selector. It returns the element instance if found, or `null` if not found. So for instance, from what you've shown of your HTML, you could do this:

```
if (document.querySelector('select[name="metric-name"] option[value="13"]')) {
    // Yes, it's there
} else {
    // No, it's not
}
```

> 2. If there is a method to check if the option exist, is it [going to] work on this scenario since my option is on the page even though is displayed only when accountId from session is not equal to 5

According to what I can find about `cfif`, the `option` *won't* be on the rendered page in the browser if that condition is true. So the above would work.

Example without the `option`:

```js
if (document.querySelector('select[name="metric-name"] option[value="13"]')) {
    console.log("Yes, it's there");
} else {
    console.log("No, it's not there");
}
```

```html
<select class="ue-select-box box-model" name="metric-name">                             
  <option value="1" selected>Logins (including from CRM)</option>
  <option value="2">Listened to a Call (including from CRM)</option>
  <option value="15">Set up a New Report/Edited a Report</option>
</select>
```

Example *with* the `option`:

```js
if (document.querySelector('select[name="metric-name"] option[value="13"]')) {
    console.log("Yes, it's there");
} else {
    console.log("No, it's not there");
}
```

```html
<select class="ue-select-box box-model" name="metric-name">                             
  <option value="1" selected>Logins (including from CRM)</option>
  <option value="2">Listened to a Call (including from CRM)</option>
  <option value="15">Set up a New Report/Edited a Report</option>
  <option value="13">Staff Activity - Deactivate</option>
</select>
```