# JavaScript check if HTML tags exists on the page

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a normal web page layout and I need to find a way to check the HTML for existing tags.

So I would have an array with for example:

```
var array = ['header', 'nav', 'article'];
```

Then the web page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>...</nav>
    </header>
    <container>
      <article></article>
    </container>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I get JavaScript to scan the page for tag which are available in the array?

Comment: Please do some research before asking on Stack Overflow, as detailed in [ask].

Comment: document.querySelectorAll(cssSelector);

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName(tagName)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I select multiple tags using getElementsByTagName?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193437/can-i-select-multiple-tags-using-getelementsbytagname)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a html tag exist on this scenario using JS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43522316/218196)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through that array and check if that tag is on the web page

```
var arr = ['header', 'nav', 'article', 'p'];

    arr.forEach(function(ele){
        if(document.getElementsByTagName(ele).length > 0)
      {
        console.log(ele + ' found');
      }
      else
      {
        console.log(ele + ' not found');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

If using jquery is an option then you can get all elements that match the tag with:

```
$('header, nav, article')
```

Reference https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/